# Different way of work with module require() parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

If you want pass parameters into module you do it like this:

**index.js**

```
let test = require("./module.js")(something);
```

**module.js**

```
module.exports = (something) => {
    //Working with `something` here
};
```

But is there so way how to do it without using `module.exports = (var) => {}`?

More specifficaly to be able to write for example code outside function container and then at the end of file do `module.exports`?

Or you are able to just do this?

```
const globalSomething;

(something) => {
  globalSomething = something;
}

module.exports = heavyWorkWith(globalSomething);
```

If you understand me.

Comment: Export more than just a function? You can export whatever you want

Comment: I know but when you want to get parameters defined in `index.js` you need to use exact this format :D

Comment: No you don't, you can use a named function, or a class declaration

Comment: Can you show me how then please? :D

Comment: Absolutely, just a moment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't restricted to an unnamed function to pass around parameters, you can use a named function

```
export default function myExport(something) {
   //...
}
```

or even a class

```
export default class myExport() {
    constructor(something) {
        //...
    }
}
```

And on the inverse side, import:

```
const myExport = require('./myModuleOrWhatever');
const foo = new myExport(something);
```

Even moreso, you can just pass along module constants with your anonymous module export

```
const bar = somethingElse;
const baz = moreElse;

/*
alernatively
export default const bar = somethingElse
*/
module.exports = {
    foo: (something) => {
        //Working with `something` here
    },
    bar,
    baz,
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much :D Its nice :D I almost started to wonder that javascript is limited lang :D